# MPV for Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: 23.04

Currently I use [MPC-HC](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/releases) for streaming video on Windows, but I'm moving to Ubuntu 23.04 in a couple days and apparently there is no linux version for it.

So now I'm concidering MPV but I can't find a version for Ubuntu 23.04, so anybody please could give a link for it, if available? And if it's not available, What media players should I get? (anything but VLC, [they](https://commiesubs.com/playback/) say it's not that good)

And I don't really prefar re-downloading the LTS version due to limited bandwidth, but I'll if it's better for a new and unexperienced user. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't find a version for Ubuntu 23.04

Where did you look?

[image]

https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/mpv